# Why is "Your daily reviews" count shown when I am not logged in?

Tags: support, bug, review

I was going through one of my suggested edits without logging in and I noticed this:

[image: Image of the suggested edits review queue from a logged out perspective. It includes "Your daily review 0/20"]

Why is the "Your daily reviews" count shown to me when I am not logged in?

Comment: It also [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29V7l.png) if you're logged in and don't have enough reputation to perform any reviews in that review queue.

Comment: Because anonymous users also have a limit in the review queue?

Comment: Question is, is it always 0, or does it actually show number of reviews you made this day? If always 0 it's just display bug, that doesn't hide the useless info. If showing actual count, it's a more severe bug.